# coldfusion and wsdl datatypes

Tags: coldfusion, wsdl, coldfusion-9

I am trying to use a wsdl with cold fusion 9, but every time I try to make I try to call a function, I get an AxisFault Internal Server Error.  I think the error is from the wsdl wanting data type's and cold fusion not casting them properly, like "dateTime" or things like

```
<xs:element name="MaximumNumberOfMatches" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Is there a hack to get around this, as it seems using javaCast isn't getting the job done.

For passing the dateTime, I found this code to work

```
myJavaDate = CreateObject("java", "java.util.GregorianCalendar").getInstance();
myJavaDate.setTimeInMillis(0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember running into trouble with [PositiveInteger's](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/types/PositiveInteger.html) back in CF8. Things may have changed in CF9, but back then creating an instance of that class was the only thing that seemed to do the trick:

```
 num = createObject("java", "org.apache.axis.types.PositiveInteger").init(123);
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing I would do is a trim of your xml. Often times a leading space can cause the problem.

```
<cfhttp method = "get"...>
<cfset myXML = trim(cfhttp.FileContent)>
```

Are you the owner of this service or is it out of your control?  The only time i've gotten this error was when there was a problem creating the wsdl output.  Server configuration changed and the cfc bombed.

HTH

P.S. the actual error would be a help.

Comment: The xml I posted is from the wsdl.  And the error is not helpful, but I will post it anyway. "The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Internal system error. Please try again later.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
 {http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context}fault:2Internal system error. Please try again later."

Comment: if trimming the response doesn't work, change your cfargument type to `string`. (assuming you're using cffunction and passing in the xml data as `type = "xml"`)